# about Leetcode 569. Median Employee Salary

Tags: mysql

```
SUM(CASE
WHEN Employee.Salary = alias.Salary THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) >= ABS(SUM(SIGN(Employee.Salary - alias.Salary)))
```

> It is not hard to understand that for either of these two elements, the difference (absolute value) of its bigger and smaller number than itself in this array is 1, which is the exactly frequency of a element in the distinct array.
>
> So in general, the median's frequency should be equal or grater than the absolute difference of its bigger elements and small ones in an array no matter whether it has odd or even amount of numbers and whether they are distinct. "

from approach 1[solution from the problem](https://leetcode.com/articles/median-employee-salary/)

how to understand the explanation from the quote?

Comment: This seems to be more of a mathematical question  about statistics than about SQL.

Comment: Did you read the two paragraphs before that in the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full query from your link is

```
SELECT
    Employee.Id, Employee.Company, Employee.Salary
FROM
    Employee,
    Employee alias
WHERE
    Employee.Company = alias.Company
GROUP BY Employee.Company , Employee.Salary
HAVING SUM(CASE
    WHEN Employee.Salary = alias.Salary THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) >= ABS(SUM(SIGN(Employee.Salary - alias.Salary)))
ORDER BY Employee.Id
```

The HAVING clause could also be written as

```
HAVING SUM(Employee.Salary = alias.Salary)
       >=
       ABS(SUM(Employee.Salary > alias.Salary) - SUM(Employee.Salary < alias.Salary))
```

For distinct salary values

- `SUM(Employee.Salary = alias.Salary)` is the frequency (which is always 1 for distinct values because the row will only match itself)
- `SUM(Employee.Salary > alias.Salary)` is the number of smaller values
- `SUM(Employee.Salary < alias.Salary)` is the number of bigger values

The pseudo code could be

```
HAVING frequency >= abs(smaller_values - bigger_values)
```

And that is what the author is telling:

> [..] the median's frequency should be equal or grater than the
>   absolute difference of its bigger elements and small ones [..]

Note that if the salary values are not always distinct, the correct "translation" of the code would be

```
HAVING frequency * frequency >= abs(smaller_values * frequency - bigger_values * frequency)
```

However - The result is the same.